# Invalid hook call. Is it possible to call hooks or async functions outside body of function component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to make this work without changing my function component to a class based component:

```
export default function SendVerificationCode({
  route,
  navigation
}: NativeStackScreenProps<
  NativeStackParameterList,
  'SendVerificationCode'
>): JSX.Element {

  async function getVerificationCode(
    passwordApi: PasswordApi,
    agencyKey: number,
    username: string,
    email: string,
    verificationCode: string
  ): Promise<void> {
    const response = await passwordApi.getReset(
      new GetResetRequest({
        agencyKey: agencyKey,
        email: email,
        username: username,
        verificationCode: verificationCode
      })
    );

    verifyCodeContext.userName = username;
    navigation.navigate('VerifyCode', {
      copyrightYear: 2021,
      version: '0.0.0.1'
    });
  }

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    getVerificationCode(
      new PasswordApi(),
      1234,
      data.username,
      data.email,
      '123'
    );
  };

  return (
    <UnauthenticatedTemplate copyrightYear={year} version={version}>
      <Form
        style={styles.form}
        submitText="Send Code"
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        schema={SendVerificationCodeSchema}
      >
        <FCTextField name="username" placeholder="Username" />
        <FCTextField name="email" placeholder="Email" />
      </Form>
    </UnauthenticatedTemplate>
  );
}
```

The onSubmit works perfectly fine until I call `getVerificationCode`

my axios function getReset looks like:

```
public getReset(
    getResetRequest: GetResetRequest,
    cancelToken?: CancelToken
  ): Promise<StandardResponse<GetResetResponse>> {
    return this.get(
      this.configuration.portal,
      '/mvc/api/password/reset',
      classToPlain(getResetRequest, BaseApi.classTransformOptions),
      cancelToken,
      new StandardResponse<GetResetResponse>(GetResetResponse)
    );
  }
```

Comment: What happens when you call `getVerificationCode`?

Comment: Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: App does not crash but gives a warning and the network request `getVerificationCode` never gets called

Comment: One question, as you are using jsx elements, are you importing react?

Comment: Yes I am using react import. My react imports are not an issue.

Comment: No, React hooks can only be called in React function components and custom React hooks. `async` functions are plain Javascript, they can be invoked anywhere really. Can you update your question to include all relevant code, specifically `GetResetRequest`, so that we can see what it's doing? For the unhandled rejection error you may just need to surround the asynchronous code with a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your app, you're calling a hook (functions that start with use such as useState) inside a function that isn't a React component, I don't think the issue is within the code snippets you've included, perhaps the issue is in the screen you're navigating to?

Go through your code and look for hooks and make sure that they aren't in a function, examples:

```js
// Right implementation
function SomeComponent(props) {
  const hook = useHook()
  return <View />
}

// Wrong implementation
function SomeComponent(props) {
  function nestedFunction() {
    const hook = useHook()
  }
  return <View />
}
```

Hope you find this helpful